# grab a return variable from a $.get function

Tags: jquery

I need to grab the variable `prodata` from this function (which is populated dynamically), in order to use it in another function. But I don't know I can use `return`. Where to put return so that I can use prodata outside of this function.

```
$.get("proDB.txt", function(data) {
    var lines=data.split(/\n/);
    var numberofmodels=lines.length-2;
    var prodata=[];
    var i;
    var fieldnames=lines[0].split(/\t/);
    for (i = 1; i < lines.length-1; ++i) {
        var fields=lines[i].split(/\t/);
        var j;
        prodata[i]={};
        for (j = 0; j < fields.length; ++j) {
            prodata[i][fieldnames[j]]=fields[j];
        }
    }
    //remplir la liste déroulante:
    var options = '';
    for (i = 1; i < lines.length-1; ++i) {
        if (prodata[i]['name'].indexOf("elly") >= 0) {
            options += '<option value="' + prodata[i]['id'] + '" selected>' + prodata[i]['name']+', '+prodata[i]['brand']+', '+prodata[i]['model']+'</option>';
        }else{
            options += '<option value="' + prodata[i]['id'] + '">' + prodata[i]['name']+', '+prodata[i]['brand']+', '+prodata[i]['model']+'</option>';
        }
    }
$("#userchosenpromodel").html(options);
}, 'text'); //$.get
```

and then I need to access and use `prodata` within

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    //computeUserDimensions(prodata[proId]);
});

function computeUserDimensions(line){
```

Comment: $.get() is asynchronous, so there's no way to return a value from it.  You'll need to utilize the variable from somewhere within your $.get() callback.

Comment: You can't return the value outside as the execution is asynchronous, you have to use the variable in the callback or in a function you call from the callback.

Comment: how to use the variable in a function I call from the callback, can you give an example?

Comment: or maybe I can read my file differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use it outside of that function, otherwise it will get used before it exists. An alternative is to use deferred objects.

```
var request = $.get("myurl",handler,"text");
```

Now, if you need to get at the data from `handler`, just use this:

```
request.done(function(data){
    // use the data here, but not outside
    console.log(data)
});
```

One way around this to keep your work in the handler but allow you to get the modified var is to store a reference to it outside, and only access it within a .done().

```
var prdata;
var request = $.get("myurl",function(data){
    prdata = data;
},"text");
console.log(prdata); // undefined because request isn't done
request.done(function(){
    console.log(prdata); // IS defined because request IS done
});
console.log(prdata); // undefined because request still isn't done
```

Comment: I am a newbie! CAn you please develop your advice for my example? I don't know what to do with `handler`...

Comment: `handler` is your existing code, `function(data) {...`

Comment: @user130482 `handler` is the function that can access the AJAX call response. You can't return the response from your function.

Comment: ok thanks. The variable I need to use outside is `prodata`, not `data`

Comment: @user130482 you can't get it outside. you can't get data outside either.

Comment: then I'll use your way and get through request.done... is prodata available in there?

Comment: I need to use prodata in a another function a little bit lower in my file :  `$('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {...}`....I guess it is not possible. Can you advise on how to restructure all that so I can do what i need?

Comment: The answer from Dustin did the trick. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user130482 I strongly suggest against using `async: false`. It can and will cause a bad user experience when the server or network hangs for a second+. While a synchronous request is being sent, the browser is locked up until it completes. You won't notice this when working locally from the server because your network speed is near instant.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks @Kevin B, what do you suggest then? I would need a function that reads my text file and returns this array `prodata`from it. Even better would to move this function to my other js file: function.js

Comment: I am gonna test what you edited in your answer. I'll get back to you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am testing your new suggestion: The problem is that I need to access prodata from within `$('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {...});` How can I pass `request` into this?

Comment: Actually thinks are clearer: there are two issues here. 1: I need to populate prodata[] dynamically as you can see line 11 of my example. and 2: I need to be accessible from within another function. I am editing my question to make it clear.

Comment: @user130482 Have i not made it clear enough that you CAN'T do that?

Comment: Ok that works. But now it led to another problem regarding the event that I ask here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837179/jquery-global-variables-usable-everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to make prodata global, as before, but disable to submit button until it has been populated. Something like this:

```
// Declare prodata here
var prodata = [];

// Disable submitbutton so it won't be clicked before prodata is ready
$('#submitbutton').attr("disabled", "disabled");

$.get("proDB.txt", function(data) {
    var lines=data.split(/\n/);
    var numberofmodels=lines.length-2;
    var i;
    var fieldnames=lines[0].split(/\t/);
    for (i = 1; i < lines.length-1; ++i) {
        var fields=lines[i].split(/\t/);
        var j;
        prodata[i]={};
        for (j = 0; j < fields.length; ++j) {
            prodata[i][fieldnames[j]]=fields[j];
        }
    }
    //remplir la liste déroulante:
    var options = '';
    for (i = 1; i < lines.length-1; ++i) {
        if (prodata[i]['name'].indexOf("elly") >= 0) {
            options += '<option value="' + prodata[i]['id'] + '" selected>' + prodata[i]['name']+', '+prodata[i]['brand']+', '+prodata[i]['model']+'</option>';
        }else{
            options += '<option value="' + prodata[i]['id'] + '">' + prodata[i]['name']+', '+prodata[i]['brand']+', '+prodata[i]['model']+'</option>';
        }
    }
    $("#userchosenpromodel").html(options);

    // Enable submitbutton since prodata is now available
    $('#submitbutton').removeAttr("disabled");
}, 'text'); //$.get

$('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // Do an if check here just in case we somehow got here when prodata wasn't ready
    if ( prodata.length > 0 ) computeUserDimensions(prodata[proId]);
});

function computeUserDimensions(line){}
```

This will allow you to access prodata from your click method, because the click method will never be accessed before prodata is available.

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, it gets problematic using the variable outside of the callback due to the asynchronous nature of the $.get call. However, if you need to, you can make the call synchronous. In order to do that, you have to use the more generic $.ajax instead of $.get, and pass it async:false, and you need to define prodata above the ajax call:

```
var prodata=[];
$.ajax({
  url: 'proDB.txt',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(data) {
      // do stuff to prodata here
  }
});
// use prodata here
```

Comment: nice...I am gonna try this

Comment: Kevin B rises an important point about the fact that asynchronous functions hang until they are completed...this can be a problem.