# jquery global variables usable everywhere

Tags: jquery

I am starting to doubt that jquery is easy to use and flexible.
I have this:

```
var prodata=[];
var request = $.get("proDB.txt", function(data) {
    var lines=data.split(/\n/);
    var numberofmodels=lines.length-2;
    //var prodata=[];
    var i;
    prodata.push(0);
    var fieldnames=lines[0].split(/\t/);
    for (i = 1; i < lines.length-1; ++i) {
        var fields=lines[i].split(/\t/);
        prodata.push(i);            
        var j;
        prodata[i]={};
        for (j = 0; j < fields.length; ++j) {
            //prodata[i][fieldnames[j]]=fields[j];
            var str=fieldnames[j];
            prodata[i][str]=fields[j];

        }
    }

    //FILL THE DROPDOWN LIST
    var options = '';
    for (i = 1; i < lines.length-1; ++i) {
        if (prodata[i]['name'].indexOf("elly") >= 0) {
            var iselected = i;
        }
        options += '<option label="bla" value="' + prodata[i]['id'] + '">' + prodata[i]['name']+', '+prodata[i]['brand']+', '+prodata[i]['model']+'</option>';
    }
    $("#userchosenpromodel").html(options);
    //SELECT DEFAULT OPTION
    $('#userchosenpromodel option[value="' + prodata[iselected]['id'] + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
}, 'text'); //$.get
```

I would like to use `proId`, lower in my code, after it's been defined like that:

```
//SUBMIT FORM
$('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    request.done(function(){
        proId=$('#userchosenpromodel option[selected="selected"]').val();
        proId=parseInt(proId);
        computeUserDimensions(prodata[proId]);
    });
});
    console.log(proId);
```

How to?

Same problem for `prodata`...I have `request.done` that I can't get rid of

Thanks

Comment: Umm.. simple timing issue. `console.log` is running before `request.done` so it will log the value before the change.

Comment: You can't. I'm sorry to keep answering it the same way, but... you can't. Ajax is asynchronous. If you want to write the code in this way, you must make it synchronous and deal with the side-effects that brings. Otherwise, re-organize your code so taht you don't need proId outside of the done callback.

Comment: you're right...I am not used to this type of algorythmic

Comment: PROBLEM: in the fonction `var request = $.get(.....` I set the default selected option in a select: `//SELECT DEFAULT OPTION
  $('#userchosenpromodel option[value="' + prodata[iselected]['id'] + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");`  and as you can see, later, in the `request.done`, I get the option that is selected....BUT in the meantime the user can select another option....so I would need to get not the option I preselected but the option selected by the user.....any idea how to do this so I can pass the right proId to the computeUserDimensions function?

Comment: That all depends on your application. From what you said I would prevent the user from sending another request until the first one completes.

Comment: I need the user to be able to choose another <option> than the default one that I set in the <select>. When he click on the submit button, I need the code to account for the user choice.

Comment: @user130482 The code within done will act on the page at the time done is ran, so if hte user changes it between var request and the .done, the .done will catch that change.

Comment: Ok so my code is good, because I put the .done in the `$('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {` right?  But I am testing it right now, and whatever option the user selects manually, the proId stays the same (the one set by default)...I don't understand. Is the selector `$('#userchosenpromodel option[selected="selected"]')` correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a problem with jQuery but with asynchronous/event based logic.

You **can't** synchronously use the return of an asynchronous function. You must use the result in the callback or in a function you call from the callback :

```
request.done(function(){
    var proId=$('#userchosenpromodel option[selected="selected"]').val();
    console.log(proId);
});
```

Comment: "You don't have a problem with jQuery but with asynchronous/event based logic."  ...you're right. I am used to standard, oldshool code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
request.done(function(){
    proId=$('#userchosenpromodel option[selected="selected"]').val();
    doSomethingWithProId();
});

function doSomethingWithProId(){
    console.log(proId);
}
```

OR so it doesn't need to be a Global

```
request.done(function(){
    var proId=$('#userchosenpromodel option[selected="selected"]').val();
    doSomethingWithProId(proId);
});

function doSomethingWithProId(proId){
    console.log(proId);
}
```

The second solution in my mind is better. Whatever you need to do with proId build your functions to pass in that data. That way you don't need to pollute the global scope. Sounds like you need a better understanding of JS.

Comment: see PROBLEM in the comments of my question